# Can't add Loop to Drag Scroll Slider without breaking the dragging functionality

Tags: javascript, for-loop, drag

I've just followed this tutorial on Youtube to add a drag scroll to any scroll elements (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C9EWifQ5xqA&t=115s&ab_channel=WesBos) It worked and was extremely helpful. My only issue is I would like to apply this to multiple sliders on one page. I believe I have to create some form of 'For Loop' but I'm struggling to get anything working. Whenever I seem to add a For Loop it breaks the functionality and stops working.

Heres the JS I currently have which works.

```
var scrollSlider = document.querySelector(".scroll-slider1, .scroll-slider2");
let isDown = false;
let startX;
let scrollLeft;
 
scrollSlider.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    isDown = true;
    scrollSlider.classList.add('active');
    startX = e.pageX;
    scrollLeft = scrollSlider.scrollLeft;
});

scrollSlider.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    isDown = false;
    scrollSlider.classList.remove('active');
});

scrollSlider.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
    isDown = false;
    scrollSlider.classList.remove('active');
});

scrollSlider.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(!isDown) return;
    const x = e.pageX;
    const scroll = x - startX;
    scrollSlider.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - scroll;
});
```

Could anyone help me add some form of loop to this, so it gets applied to every drag slider on the page rather than just the first slider? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Get all scroll sliders
const scrollSliders = document.querySelectorAll(".scroll-slider1, .scroll-slider2");

// Loop through each scroll slider
scrollSliders.forEach(scrollSlider => {
  let isDown = false;
  let startX;
  let scrollLeft;
 
  // Add event listeners for each scroll slider
  scrollSlider.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      isDown = true;
      scrollSlider.classList.add('active');
      startX = e.pageX;
      scrollLeft = scrollSlider.scrollLeft;
  });

  scrollSlider.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
      isDown = false;
      scrollSlider.classList.remove('active');
  });

  scrollSlider.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
      isDown = false;
      scrollSlider.classList.remove('active');
  });

  scrollSlider.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      if(!isDown) return;
      const x = e.pageX;
      const scroll = x - startX;
      scrollSlider.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - scroll;
  });

});
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm struggling to see the difference. Could you point it out to me so I understand better?

Comment: Hi Jason, I have edited the code, and added comments explaining what I did.

Comment: You're a Star. Thank you! That worked the first time. I tried playing with it again for a couple of hours and I managed to loop it myself and get both sliders to drag scroll. But it wasn't right as I would scroll one slider and both would scroll. But this code worked immediately exactly as I wanted Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, Jason! I'm really glad that the code worked just fine.